# Firebase Database - Login

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, authentication

I have a register page working well, this is my database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hQMx.png)

Each one has an ID and you Login using Username and password,
And I am using this code, to verify if the username is in database.

```
ref.child("accounts").orderByChild("lowerun").equalTo(username.toLowerCase()).once("value",snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
          const userData = snapshot.val();
          console.log(userData)
        }
    })
```

But how do I get the password for the username?

Comment: Hi! What does that `console.log()` prints to the console?

Comment: it writes: "(2) empty, [] "

Comment: Storing plaintext passwords in the database for anyone to read is extremely insecure.  This is the problem that Firebase Authentication is meant to solve.  I strongly suggest you use that as a proper sign-in system.

Comment: it is encrypted

Answer (score 0):

Dudis! Welcome to SO! It looks like you're using Firebase Realtime Database? I think you're using the database API incorrectly if you're trying to fetch user number 1 in your accounts. Here is something you could try:

```
database
  .ref("main/accounts")
  .child(userId)
  .once("value", snapshot => {
    // check if snapshot exists
    // log your snapshot.val()
})
```

Also, as Doug suggested, I would strongly suggest using Firebase Authentication.

Comment: thats the problem, how would I get the user ID just by his username?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you should already know the userId. If you're trying to retrieve the user's data by his username then use 'Dudisss' as the userId instead of the number one. Your data structure would then look like: 
{
  main: {
    accounts: {
      Dudisss: {
        // user data
      }
    }
  }
}